# Convert millivolts from shunt on DMM on a 50A, 75 mV Shunt

Tags: amperage, shunt

Please excuse my awful math/s. Can anyone please help me calculate/convert the mV reading from a 50A shunt? For example if i was reading 1.5mv how do i convert please. Please keep it simple as math is (obviously) not my strong point!
Thank you

---

Slightly embarrassed at the state of my maths but thank you all for comments. However going with (50/75) x the Amp reading isnt agreeing with my two ammeters!

The ammeters are reading 2.06 and 2.12, and the DMM is reading 12.0mV - so - (50/75)x12 =8 oops. Any ideas folks?

---

It is a series circuit 12v battery, fuse holder with cheap ammeter plugged here, switch, bulb, earthed through chinese shunt with second ammeter reading here along with DMM. Appreciate shunt and cheap ammeters may not be 100% but im not getting close even. How might ammeters not be reading total circuit current pls?.

---

Schematic (description below)
[image]

The two ovals at (a) represent a fuse holder (fuse removed). into this is inserted an ammeter (c) which accepts the removed fuse (b).
(d)represents the shunt with the other ammeter attached and this is where the voltmeter reading are taken off either side of shunt.
Excuse poor schematic drawing/symbols etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9SMQ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Schematic added by Transistor. OP to edit / correct.*

---

Update - PROBLEM SOLVED Brilliant - I was taking the mV reading from the wrong place, on the large, outer terminals when I should have been reading from the the smaller terminals. Here I get 3.5mv which then gives me a close amperage figure (50/75*3.5=2.4).

Lesson learnt - thanks to all - admin please feel free to edit this to make it more useful to others.

Comment: Are the ammeters reading the total current in the circuit? A diagram may help.. Do the ammeters have a scaling factor?

Comment: Appended a description of circuit to post if anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: So where is the circuit? I think we all want to find out what is happening here...

Comment: I described it above ... I'll upload a schematic later if poss (grandchild in the house).

Comment: So, have I understood correctly that at "d" you have the shunt which has an ammeter connected with it - if so, then these should be in series ie cable in : shunt : ammeter : cable out and the voltmeter should be across the shunt only, if they are in parallel this will cause an incorrect (low) reading on the voltmeter due to resistances in parallel.

Comment: @NickHudson: I've added a clearer schematic for you. Please edit it to reflect your actual circuit.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the solution. One of the reasons for the small terminals is to ensure that you're not measuring the voltage drop across the high-current terminals due to bad connections, etc.

Comment: Always something simple!  Really enjoying the learning

Answer (score 2):

If 75mv is the full scale reading for 50A, then :

Edit 2 : So

```
(50A / 75mV) * 1.5mV = 1A
```

Where 50A is max shunt current, and 75mV is full scale reading and 1.5mV is the reading obtained by the OP.
Note, one can see that the mV, as units, will cancel leaving the result to be A.

Edit : the shunt has already been calibrated, you may find small cuts in it to "match the resistance to give 75mV at 50A.

Comment: "*... so (50 / 75) * 1.5 should give you the current.*". Um, that will just give you '1 A' no matter what the mV reading is.

Comment: @Transistor So (50 / 75) * 22mV = 14.67A, not the 1A you suggest...

Comment: @Transistor If I follow your calculation in your comment below, why does it give the same as my calculation?

Comment: I know you know how to calculate the true reading but you have no variable in your equation. How did 1.5 become 22 mV?

Comment: Ah, I see the 1.5 mV in the OP. It's not clear in your answer.

Comment: @Transistor I just picked 22mV to test the expression that you told me did not work : in my answer I put (50 / 75) * 1.5 , which was the 1.5mV given by the OP - which was the variable...

Comment: This answer is very sloppy with units.  This is not acceptable in engineering.  For example "(50 /75) * 1.5 should give you current".  No.  It gives you a dimensionless quantity, 1.0 in this case.  That is definitely not current.  Ping me when you've fixed all this and I'll undo the downvote.

Comment: @OlinLathrop if you read edit 2 - that shows the units...

Comment: Much better.  Downvote undone.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of measured A = Vm * 50A/75mV is correct (Vm measured in mV).

You need to connect the meter **directly** to the shunt and you need to use the "inner" terminals on the shunt (usually they are smaller screws) to go **directly to the meter (and nowhere else)** and the **outer** terminals on the shunt carry the high current.

It should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMjRRh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors marked "?" represents wiring resistance and internal resistance of the shunt.

If you were to (say) connect the meter to ground rather than directly to the shunt then the resistance of the connections would add to the shunt resistance and you would get a significant error most likely.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - this is the answer. On the smaller terminal I get 3.5mv which then gives me a close amperage figure (50/75*3.5=2.4).

Comment: @NickHudson So, I gave you the correct calculation, but the issue was the circuit construction - well done for sorting it.

Comment: Yes. the calc was the only one it could be!! The help here is really useful and very informative. I'm learning!! ta

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the ohm value of the shunt. Without knowing that this cannot be determined from the provided information.

Edit: Yeah, I missed the "75 mV" part in the title. With that its just a matter of multiplying mV reading by 50/75.

My Bad.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, when you have enough rep you can leave comments.

Comment: @Norm: There's enough info in the question to calculate the resistance, if required. Nick has supplied the full-scale current and voltage and the resistance can be calculated from these. In any case, it's not required. \$ I = mV \times \frac {50}{75}  = mV \times \frac {2}{3} \$ and the answer will be in amps. The formula doesn't mention resistance. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: This does answer the question. But wrongly. If Op knows current through the shunt and the voltage across it, he knows the resistance. R = V / I or 0.012 / 2.09 = 0.00057 ohms

Comment: Your answer is nearly fixed. The title says 75 mV not mA. It's tough in here! Don't be discouraged but when writing an answer it's a really good idea to check that you have actually answered the question and proofread before hitting submit. There are too many guys here who know what they're talking about!

Comment: +1 since content doesn't belong in the title, and I missed it originally for the same reason.  This was the OP's fault, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Look up something called *Ohm's Law*.  It says that the voltage across a resistor is the current thru the resistor times the resistance.

You know the voltage across the resistor.  Go find what resistance your shunt is.  Then divide the voltage you see by that resistance to get the current.

For example, if this is a 1 mΩ shunt, then with 1.5 mV across it, you have (1.5 mV)/(1 mΩ) = 1.5 A.

### Added

I now see that you say this shunt causes 75 mV across it with 50 A thru it.  That means it is really a (75 mV)/(50 A) = 1.5 mΩ resistor.  To get the current, plug in this resistance and the measured voltage into Ohm's law.  For example, if the reading is 1.5 mV, then the current is (1.5 mV)/(1.5 mΩ) = 1.0 A.

In summary, divide the voltage reading by 1.5 mΩ, and you get the current.

Comment: So, if you have 75mV then 75 / 1mΩ is surely 75A ? But the OP says it is a 50A shunt...

Comment: @Sol: First, the 1 mOhm value was a *example* to show how to do the math.  Note "For **example**, **if** ..." in the last sentence.  Second, the OP hadn't said what the resistance nor maximum voltage of the shunt was when I wrote this answer.

Comment: The Op had given sufficient information in the original post - can't understand how you missed it...

Comment: @Sol: The information was originally hidden in the title only.  In any case, I have updated the answer to his specific case.  I don't see what your problem with this is.